# How do I go about showing the cardinality of two sets are the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

How do I go about showing that the cardinality of the set of natural numbers and the cardinality of the cartesian product of integers is the same?:

$$|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z|$$

Directly $|\Bbb N| = \aleph_0$ and I can separate the right side like this: $|\Bbb Z||\Bbb Z|$, and because the cardinality of the set of integers is $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_0$ times $\aleph$ is still $\aleph_0$ and thus they are equal. However, I need to show an example how a bijection can be used here? How do I construct a map to let me see a bijection is being used/provide that it is surjective/injective?

Comment: I know that, but how do I do it?

Comment: Do you know any bijections between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$? How about between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$?

Comment: I know that they both have bijections but I do not how to prove it/find it

Comment: The first one (a bijection between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$) is really easy. Start with that, and show us what you get once you find it.

Comment: I can set up a table such as the top row resembles integers: 0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4... and the bottom row resembles natural numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... There is a bijection

Comment: OK, so you have that bijection. Do you see how to finish the problem is you also had a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$?

Comment: So I will just basically have each element in N point to exactly one in NxN? But how will I do it for ZxZ because the sets can go to infinity both directions(negative and positive) while the natural numbers only go positive?

Comment: Why do you think I asked first for a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Ohhhh okay, I got it now! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Well, OK. Do you then have a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$? This is the tricky part.

Comment: But how would I set a table up for me to see it? I understand what to do now, I just don't know how to let my teacher know that I know what I am doing

Comment: There is no bijection is there between N and N x N?

Comment: There are many. Why would you suddenly think that there isn't one?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Could you sum up your advices in an answer?

Comment: @Berci Sure I could. But no, thanks.

Comment: But how do you know there are many bijections N and N×N?

Comment: Don't get distracted by that. Your task is to find one. Never mind that there are many, we just need one. A common example, that has a nice intuitive picture attached to it, is Cantor's pairing, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). One that is easier to verify uses that each positive integer is the product of an odd number and a power of two, $n=2^a(2b+1)$. This gives you a bijection $n\mapsto(a,b)$ between the positive integers and $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588190/cardinality-of-a-set-of-natural-lattice-points-versus-natural-numbers

Answer (score 2):

Much like eating a steak, this problem is easier to swallow if you cut it into smaller pieces and chew on them. Specifically here you can do it in three steps:

1. There is a bijection $f$ between $\Bbb{N\times N}$ and $\Bbb N$.
2. There is a bijection $g$ between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb N$.
3. Now define, $h(m,k)=f(g(m),g(k))$, and show it is a bijection.

If indeed you succeeded in the first two steps, then the third is easy.

- $h$ is injective, since if $h(m,k)=h(m',k')$, then $f(g(m),g(k))=f(g(m'),g(k'))$. But $f$ is injective, so $g(m)=g(m')$ and $g(k)=g(k')$. But $g$ is also injective. So $m=m'$ and $k=k'$ as wanted.
- $h$ is surjective, since if $n$ is any natural number, then since $f$ is surjective, there are some $s,t\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(s,t)=n$. But also $g$ is surjective, so there are some $m,k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $g(m)=s$ and $g(k)=t$. Therefore $h(m,k)=n$ as wanted.